# Questions about complete primitive in Orindary Differential Equations

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I am working on this two problems:

1. $y = c_{1}\cdot\cos(ax+c_2)$
2. $y = c_{1}x^{3} + \frac{c_2}{x}$

For number $1$: I did the first and second derivative,$y' = -ac_{1}\cdot\sin(ax+c_2)$ and for the second derivative is $y'' = -a^{2}c_{1}\cdot\cos(ax+c_2)$ and by the given($y = c_{1}\cdot\cos(ax+c_2)$) this will become $y'' = -a^{2}y$ which will become $y''+ a^{2}y = 0$. The question here is this doesn't give me the solution I started with because this ODE gives $y = c_{1}\cos(ax) +c_{2}\sin(ax)$ not $y = c_{1}\cdot\cos(ax+c_2)$. Are they the same answer? The answer on this question is $y''+ a^{2}y = 0$.

For number $2$: I am having problems with it I did the first and the second derivative $y' = 3c_{1}x^{2} - \frac{c_{2}}{x^{2}}$ and $y'' = 6c_{1}x +\frac{2c_{2}}{x^{3}}$. And I am struggling on this problem. The answer of this question is $x^{2}y''-xy' = 3y$ any hints I will appreciate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that for the first one we can use the addition formula for cosine,
$$\cos(a+b)=\cos a\cos b-\sin a\sin b$$
So
$$c_1\cos(ax+c_2)=c_1\big(\cos(ax)\cos(c_2)-\sin(ax)\sin(c_2)\big) \\ =c_1\cos(c_2)\cos(ax)+(-c_1\sin(c_2))\sin(ax)$$
Just call $c_1\cos(c_2)=C_1$ and $-c_2\sin(c_2)=C_2$ so you get $C_1\cos(ax)+C_2\sin(ax)$. In other words $c_1\cos(ax+c_2)$ and $c_1\cos(ax)+c_2\sin(ax)$ satisfy the same ODE, $y''+a^2y=0$.

The second one is just algebra. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

For the second DE,  you can read this   [Cauchy-Euler's differential equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%E2%80%93Euler_equation):
$$y = c_{1}x^{3} + \frac{c_2}{x}$$
Substitute $x=e^t$
$$y = c_{1}e^{3t} + {c_2}e^{-t}$$
This looks like the solution of a second order linar differnetial equation with conctant coefficients
$$r=-1 \text { and } r=3$$
Form the characterisitic polynomial:
$$(r+1)(r-3)=0$$
$$r^2-2r-3=0$$
Form the differential equation:
$$y''-2y'-3y=0$$
Now note that:
$$\dfrac {d}{dt}=\dfrac {dx}{dt}\dfrac {d}{dx}=e^t\dfrac {d}{dx}=
x\dfrac {d}{dx}$$
The DE becomes:
$$x\dfrac {d}{dx}\left ( x\dfrac {dy}{dx}\right)-2x\dfrac {dy}{dx}-3y=0$$
$$x^2\dfrac {d^2y}{dx^2}-x\dfrac {dy}{dx}-3y=0$$